# How to post photo to WordPress will add it to Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I would like to endup having this functionality:

When a logged in user of a selfhosted WP-website posts a photo to a gallery, the photo is automatically posted to the facebook page of the website owner. This should of course happen only after admins approval.

Not sure where to start:

- Should I find a gallery that is able to do this?
- Should I code it myself? If so, where to begin?

Comment: Pity that someone found this question reason for giving -1. I would never ask a question if i hadn't thought it through and tried to figure out myself first. I tried finding plugins for WP, and looked at other posts at this forum. I just don't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for image galleries in wordpress, and there are plugins that allow posting to facebook... You might want to start by looking at those, and seeing what already exists, then go from there to start coding your own solution, if they don't fit your need.
Here, for example, is an image gallery plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Here's one for a link to facebook: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-link-to-facebook/

After you peruse what's available, try posting any further questions here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, which is a wordpress-specific forum.

Comment: Thank You Jennifer S, for replying. I get completely lost in these apps. However, i will fight my way through :-)